# Почему возникла ошибка?

Tags: php

Есть код.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('text.txt'), true);
for ($i=0; $i < count($data['data']); $i++) {
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date'] ;
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['value'] ;
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"<a href='/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date="echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date'];"&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true'>";
echo"</td>";

echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

Вот эта часть кода выдает ошибку `depart_date="echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date'];"`

Сама ошибка **syntax error unexpected t_echo, expecting ',' or ';'**

Помогите ее исправить и объясните пожалуйста почему она выскакивает. Спасибо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исправил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

надо не

```
echo"<a href='/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date="echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date'];"&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true'>";
```

а

```
echo"<a href='/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=".$data['data'][$i]['depart_date']."&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true'>";
```

Потому что `echo` в `echo` - так не делают. Пишут либо конкатенацию переменной со строкой, которую выводят, либо переменную помещают в строку и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, теперь знаю ))